# Adjacent divs containing spans overlap when parent div is styled with flexbox in Safari only

Tags: html, css, safari, pug, flexbox

Note: I have now found out that this is only happening in Safari. It seems to be working in Chrome on OSX.

Setting just the style `display: flex;` on `.hshow` makes the two child divs side by side (in a row), but they overlap. The text from `show.title` is over the text "April 6th"

I assume this has something to do with the spans. How would I make the two children of `.hshow` not overlap when they are adjacent to each other in a row?

Below is an example of the effect - two divs, one containing spans, under a parent div with the style `display: flex`. I have added other colors to make the effects more obvious. The "April 6th," the side with the spans, overlaps under the second div's text.

ON SAFARI:

[image]

ON CHROME:

[image]

The following is in Jade/Pug, but can be read as fairly simple HTML.

```
.hshow
    .hshow__left // IN PICTURE: RED BACKGROUND

        h2.hshow__date
            span.hshow__date__month April
                span.hshow__date__num
                    span.hshow__date__num__num 6
                    span.hsow__date__num__raised th

    .hshow__right // IN PICTURE: GREEN BACKGROUND
        h2.hshow__title= show.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I figured out this was a bug in Safari only, the answer was a bit easier to come by. I have no clue why this works (thanks Safari), but applying `flex 1 0 auto` to the first-child of `.hshow` fixes the issue.

In Stylus/CSS...

```
.hshow
  display flex

  >div:first-child
    flex 1 0 auto
```

Result:

[image]